# How to call a method with two parameter one as xPath and other as sendkey value?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can I solve this issue?

```
public class myClass {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        oasEnterValue("//input[@name='user']", "user1");
        oasEnterValue("//input[@name='password']", "pwd1");     
    }

    public void oasEnterValue(String fXPath, String fText) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(fXPath)).sendKeys(fText);
    } 
}
```

I am getting `NullpointerException` at `driver.findElement(By.xpath(fXPath)).sendKeys(fText);`

Below is my full code:

```
public class myClass {
    WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void myTest() {
    browserGo("linkedin.com/");
    oasEnterValue("//input[@name='user']", "user1");
    oasEnterValue("//input[@name='password']", "pwd1");
}

public void oasEnterValue(String fXPath, String fText) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(fXPath)).sendKeys(fText);
}
public void browserGo(String fURL) {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(fURL);
}
```

Comment: pls post ur entire code from where are u passing the parameters.Is it TestNG framework??

Comment: where you initialize your driver ? @Anand B , do like driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: Here is my full code:public class myClass
 {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {

        browserGo("http://linkedin.com/");
        oasEnterValue("//input[@name='user']", "user1");
        oasEnterValue("//input[@name='password']", "pwd1");     
    }

    public void oasEnterValue(String fXPath, String fText) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(fXPath)).sendKeys(fText);
    } 


     public void browserGo(String fURL){
    
 driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.get(fURL);

}

Comment: Please put this code in the question so you can format it properly and make it easier for everyone to read.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, those XPaths don't exist. I think you want:

```
oasEnterValue("//*[@id='login-email']", "user1");
oasEnterValue("//*[@id='login-password']", "pwd1");
```